# SWT voting-based color reduction

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, ocr

I found this nice paper about color reduction

http://asp.eurasipjournals.com/content/2013/1/95

The approach sounds really interesting and i like to evaluate the algorithm.

Does anyone know if 
 - Its there any implementation public available ? 
 - Or is it "easy" to implement it for instance with opencv ( I dont have much experience with opencv, but i m willing to learn it if its necessary )

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SWT part of this you can find here https://github.com/aperrau/DetectText it detects text regions with SWT. But it works rather slow, more when several seconds per image.
Paper about this implementation is here: http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs4670/2010fa/projects/final/results/group_of_arp86_sk2357/Writeup.pdf

Comment: Thanks a lot, i used this code to get my code running. The color reduction part was simple to implemend, except some parts in the paper which were not clear at some points